# Under which conditions can "one" be used to refer to non human entity?

Tags: pronouns

I've heard that `one` is understood as referring to people if one uses `any one` as in

> Q: Which of these ice cream flavors do you want?
>   A: **Any one**.

I understand that `any one` sounds like `anyone`, but is that a reason not to use the expression?

What about other uses of `one`, such as `the first one` and `one of them`?

Comment: There are few restrictions on how you can use "one".  "I'd like to have one of those donuts.  No, not that one...  THAT one.  But I'll take any one of those cookies."

Comment: I don't understand why has someone erased my inverted question mark, so useful at that position. [:-)] And no, we don't have inverted question mark in my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One" is used as a pronoun for things *and* people.

Things:

- "Please hand me the one on the right."
- "John wants the same one as all his friends."
- "Having only one is never enough."

People:

- "Mary is the one who gave me this cold."
- "The one on the right is my sister."
- "Go in one at a time, please."

Comment: The two answers are complementary, since this one discusses "one" in general while the other one talks about the distinction "any one / anyone" in particular (mentioned in my question description). As I must accept a single answer, I choose the most general.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with definitions.

[*Anyone*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/anyone) means any person or people.

*Any One* refers to any object, person or animal mentioned in the context.

The difference is in how in how you pronounce these words. Once intonation is clear, there may be on confusion.

*Anyone* is pronounced as one word and the first syllable is stressed, while in *any one*, the *one* part is typically stressed more than *any* part.

Compare

> *A*nyone can do it.
>
> Any *o*ne of them can do it.